Applying custom sorting to array of numbers in angular
I would like to sort an array of numbers descending with custom sorting based on a number outside or inside the array in one step without splitting or filtering and reunion
I using Angular 17 and Rxjs 7.8
For example if I have this array of numbers:
items:Array<number>=[2,6,4,8,1,9,3,5,10];
and I want to sort this array based on any number for ex: 7
so expected result will be like
[6,5,4,3,2,1,8,9,10]
another example for number 4 the expected result will be:
[4,3,2,1,5,6,8,9,10]
I tried the following code with no luck
const sortBasedValue = 7
this.sortedItems = this.items.sort((a, b) => {
      if (sortBasedValue > b) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (sortBasedValue < b) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
  });


So can this custom sorting accomplished in one step?

You can do it as follows:
const sortBasedValue = 7
this.sortedItems = this.items.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a <= sortBasedValue && b <= sortBasedValue) {
        return b - a;
    } else {
        return a - b;
    }
});

The sort function takes two elements and decides which one is supposed to go first. In your situation, there are three cases:

the two numbers are above the special number: the smallest goes first
one number is above the special number, one is below: the smallest goes first
both are below: the largest goes first.

So basically, when both are less than or equal to sortBasedValue, we sort them backwards (expressed as b - a), otherwise we sort them normally (expressed as a - b).

You can try the following:


 function reorderArray(arr: number[], target: number): number[] {
      return arr
        .filter(x => x <= target)
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .concat(arr.filter(x => x > target).sort((a, b) => a - b));
    }
    

    const result = reorderArray([2,6,4,8,1,9,3,5,10], 4);
    console.log(result); // Output: [4,3,2,1,5,6,8,9,10]




Answers with only code are not usually useful. You should add some context. I would also put this in a snippet instead so it is executable in the SO answer.
